# Angular - remove LocationStrategy onPopState call back

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using locationStrategy.onPopState to handle when users click on back button.
The logic is working fine, but I got a problem.

The callback is triggered even the component don't exist anymore (by changing the route or using *ngIf).

The point seems like the angular stay a reference of the component in the LocationStragy, like the commom problem with Observables without unsubscribe.

How can I release the callback function passed to locationStrategy on ngOnDestroy?

```
  import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

  ...
 
  constructor(private location: LocationStrategy) {}

  ...

  protected preventBackButton() {
    this.location.onPopState(() => {
      if (this.stepper.selectedIndex > 0) {
        if (this.stepper.selectedIndex > this.MIN_STEP_TO_PREVENT_BACK_BUTTON) {
          this.preventChangePage();
        }
        this.stepper.previous();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    //release callback function here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution doing this:

1 - Change the angular locationStrategy.onPopState by window.addEventListener('popstate', ...);

2 - create a class arrow function variable to wrap your logic method

3 - Pass your arrow function to your listener: window.addEventListener('popstate', this.callBackEventHandle);

4 - On ngOnDestroy, remove the listener: window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.callBackEventHandle);

```
...

protected preventBackButton() {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', this.callBackEventHandle);
}

callBackEventHandle = () => {
    this.handleBackButton();
};

handleBackButton() {
    if (this.stepper.selectedIndex > 0) {
        if (this.stepper.selectedIndex > this.MIN_STEP_TO_PREVENT_BACK_BUTTON) {
            this.preventChangePage();
        }
        this.stepper.previous();
    }
}

...

ngOnDestroy() {

    window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.callBackEventHandle);
}
```